# Suggestion about keeping a track of fields

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am posting this message to get a suggestion about the best approach.

I am making a program in which users select the fields that they want to use. The list appears in the form of a table on the next screen. Depending on the chosen fields, the placeHolder in the textFields change. Therefore, I have to keep a track of selected fields.

I have considered the following approaches so far:

1. Two arrays. One stores the list of the labels on the cell and the second array stores 1/0  values. 1: field is selected, 0: not selected. Therefore I will have to obtain the name of the  field from array 1 and whether it is selected or not from the second one.
2. One array containing the 1/0 indicating whether the field is selected or not. I traverse the array to determine whether which placeHolders should be shown.
3. NSDictionary: It will contain object:"name of the fields" and key:1 or 0.

I don't find either of these options as good programming practice because there are lot of if and else statements and plus, there is a tremendous amount of repetition in the code.

Can you please suggest the best way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you think there are a lot of if/else statements.  You can do it with an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains two keys: field name and selected.  Fieldname is NSString, selected is NSNumber wrapping a boolean value.  Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you have something like:

```
NSDictionary *cellData = dataArray[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellData[@"field_name"];
if ([[cellData@["selected"] boolValue] == YES) { ... do whatever you do when the cell is selected, like add a checkmark ... }
```

You might also think about making a custom data class to hold each cell's data.  You can create properties for the label name and the selected-ness (this will avoid having to wrap and unwrap NSNumbers to represent YES/NO).  You could define methods on the custom class that return the correct label depending on the selected-ness.  Then you just create an array of these custom objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will accept your answer. Let me work on this a little more and if I still have queries, I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to figure out which one has been selected. You can use a number to mark up which one is selected.
Let's say there is 3 fields: `field0` `field1` `field2` and a number in binary `000`. Once `field1` is selected, then mark the number as `010`. Pass this number to the next screen, then you can use `&` for every filed. 
For `field0`, you may do `010 & 000` and get a result `0` which means `field0` is not selected. 
For `field1`, you may do `010 & 010` and get a result no `0` which manes `field1` is  selected.
For `field2`, you may do `010 & 100` and get a result `0` which manes `field2` is not  selected.